# Given the parameter cipher as the cipher to be decoded

Tags: java

A cipher is a secret text that represents a message. In this question, each character in the original message is represented by a String of 6 characters in the cipher. For example, the text "java", which consists of 4 characters, is represented as a 24-character string in the cipher:

kjdktizldzaecvyrvwaaemgk

In this question, you are tasked to complete the method decipher(String) for decoding the cipher by using the method decipherChar(String) given below.

```
/**
 * This method decodes a 6-character input String into a single character.
 * The first and second halves of the input String are compared lexicographically.
 * The middle character of the smaller half is then returned.
 * In case of equal halves, a space character is returned.
 * 
 * @param inputStr The 6-character String to be decoded.
 * @return The decoded character.
 */ 
public static char decipherChar(String inputStr) {
     // implementation not shown here
}
```

Instructions

- Given the parameter cipher as the cipher to be decoded.
- Check if the cipher is valid. If the cipher is an empty String, return the String message "no cipher". If the cipher does not have a length divisible by 6, return the String message "invalid cipher".
- If the cipher is valid, decode each 6-character sub-string of the cipher into a character of the original message by using the given method decipherChar(String). The decipherChar(String) method takes in a String of length 6 and returns the decoded character.
- Concatenate all the decoded characters and return the original message.

Comment: This looks like homework.  You need to actually attempt some code, and then ask a question when you get stuck.

Comment: You may be doing your brain a disservice but not allowing it to try to write the code first itself, and you may be giving it an insult by not thinking that it is capable of doing so. I'm betting that it is

Comment: sorry but i am new at java and i want to learn it thats all and i will do my best to do it thank u anyway sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String returnstring = "";

if(cipher.equals(""))
{
        return "no cipher";
}

if(cipher.length() %6!=0)
{
        return "invalid cipher";
}

if(cipher.length()==6)
{
        char A = decipherChar(cipher.substring(0,6));
        returnstring =  Character.toString(A);
}

if(cipher.length()==12)
{
        char A = decipherChar(cipher.substring(0,6));
        char B = decipherChar(cipher.substring(6,12));
        returnstring =  Character.toString(A) + Character.toString(B) ;
}

if(cipher.length()==18)
{
        char A = decipherChar(cipher.substring(0,6));
        char B = decipherChar(cipher.substring(6,12));
        char C = decipherChar(cipher.substring(12,18));
        returnstring =  Character.toString(A) + Character.toString(B) +
Character.toString(C);
}

if(cipher.length()==24)
{
        char A = decipherChar(cipher.substring(0,6));
        char B = decipherChar(cipher.substring(6,12));
        char C = decipherChar(cipher.substring(12,18));
        char D = decipherChar(cipher.substring(18,24));
        returnstring =  Character.toString(A) + Character.toString(B) +
Character.toString(C) + Character.toString(D);
}
return returnstring;
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I will give you the benefit of the doubt and help you out with a partial bit of code to get you started. And there may be a couple errors in there so be careful...

```
public static String decipher(String cipher){

    String deciphered = null;

    //check if cipher is valid
    if(isValid(cipher)){
        char[] arrChar = new char[cipher.length()/6];
        for(int i = 0; i< cipher.length()/6; i++){
            String substring = cipher.substring(i, i+6);
            arrChar[i] = decipherChar(substring);

            //now you need to combine the array of char into a string.
        }
    }
    else{
        return  _msg;
    }

    return deciphered;
}
```

Comment: thank u so much and i am really thankful to u but i am really a beginner and i dint know how to combine the array of char into a string if u have time plz tell me and thank u so much

Comment: String combined = new String(arrChar);

Comment: thank u so much again i am really thankful from the bottom of my heart and i will study ur code and understand it. may god bless you and thank u again